# Compare attributes in the model against some common attributes

Tags: html, backbone.js, marionette

I have some attributes names from the external source like,

```
var columnDetails = {
        firstname : "firstname",
        lastName : "lastName",
        place : "place",
        taluk : "taluk",
        state : "state",
        country : "country"
    };
```

and when i do the `fetch()` from server, i get the collections[collection of models], now i have to compare each `model` in the `collection` with the `columnDetails` and show/bind the propeties which are present in `columnDetails`.

**for Clarifications**
as per my understanding if we try to bind the model it will bind only the properties  we have as the same name in the model.

Please clarify this also.

Best Regards

Comment: Do you mean the objects returned from the server have different attribute names than the model uses?
E.g. the server returns `firstName: "foo"` while your model uses `fname`?

Comment: not exactly, consider the `columnDetails` is having ten fields and the model is having twenty fields, so  i have to show only the field that matches with `columnDetails` and models should be shown

Comment: Ah, ok I think I understand what you're trying to do. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `columnDetails` to your collection view's item view, then iterate over them in your template:

```
var my_template_html = "<% _.each(attributeNames, function(attributeName) { %> <li><%= model[attributeName] %></li> <% }); %>"
MyItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView({
    template:function(serialized_model) {
        return _.template(my_template_html, {
            model : serialized_model,
            attributeNames : options.attributeNames
        });
    }
});

var columnDetails = {
    firstname : "firstname",
    lastName : "lastName",
    place : "place",
    taluk : "taluk",
    state : "state",
    country : "country"
};

MyCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView({
  itemView: MyItemView, 
  itemViewOptions: {
    attributeNames: columnDetails
  } 
});
```

Here's some relevant links:

- [CollectionView's `itemViewOptions`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-itemviewoptions)
- [ItemView's `render`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#itemview-render)
- [Underscore's `template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template)

Comment: Hi Creynder thanks for the post +1, Please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691661/how-to-bind-a-attribute-to-a-item-view-in-backbone-marionette/17692140?noredirect=1#17692140 and please help me